# Unity Editor Hiccups

Tags: unity, editors, profiling, profiler

I've just started getting Editor hiccups during Play mode (new project) & unable to find out whats causing it.

Is there a way to find out what calls the editor's making to try & debug this?

Thanks

**Screenshot from profiler**

[image]

Comment: If it is a fully clear new project with no plugins, is per chance any Antivir/ Defender running that might try to scan the newly generated files?

Comment: Unless it's Windows Defnder, no, I'm at a loss as to whats causing it, I thought maybe hardware but all stability/benchmark tests come back clean

Comment: Try the released version and see if the hiccups exist there as well. If not, it's only an editor thing, so it does not matter that much.